# Struggling with 3D math concepts. Would like practice

Tags: 3d, quaternion, linear-algebra, raytracing

Hello fellow game developers!

I graduate this October with my Bachelor’s of Game Programming and Development. I took the required Calculus and Linear Algebra. While I passed the classes I feel like I learned what I needed to get by, and already feel it slipping away. Can anyone recommend some good resources to practice this kind of thing? Maybe coding challenges or something like that? A lot of games in this field require a solid understanding of it, and I just need more real-world practice then I got in my courses. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: While a great question, it's likely to generate opinionated answers, which aren't the goal of Stack Exchange sites. I'd recommend using other sources such as Reddit (*where open discussions are more accepted*) or the [Game Dev meta site](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions). You'll yield much better results.

Comment: Most modern game engines provide built in functions for just about everything you can imagine needing (*not everything, but a lot*). With that in mind, understanding mathematical concepts in algebra, geometry, trigonometry and calculus will give you a better understanding of the tools available to you for solving problems, and when they might come in handy. I know that's kind of broad, but that's just the nature of development. Understanding the tools available and how to apply them will go a very long way.

Comment: You'll use trig all the time when making games, but you might never need calculus or linear algebra unless you're doing highly specialized work like graphics programming or backend analytics. I took all of the required calculus, linear algebra, and differential equations courses for my Computer Science degree, but I'm having a hard time thinking of any times I've actually used them in years of game and mobile app development.

Comment: Oh, also, there is a [Math stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) if you ever need help with your math!

Comment: That said, they're still good to learn to build your problem-solving skills and make yourself more well-rounded.

Comment: Welcome to the Game Dev Stack Exchange. While requests for resources aren't on-topic for Q&A posts, this would be very reasonable to discuss [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development) (though it requires ≥20 rep). [Meta](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) is intended for discussing the workings and policies of GDSE.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the points and tips! I'll take a look at the links, and appreciate you taking time to help, even though my question was  a little broad for this arena. Thanks! (And thanks Kevin that took a bit of my mind as I won't be specializing as a graphics programmer.)